# select rows of a matrix with specific condition

Tags: r

I have the below matrix that I imported it by

```
data <- as.matrix(read.table("sample1.txt"), header = T)
```

Then I convert it as a data frame by

```
data.df <- as.data.frame(data)
```

but I cannot get a subset of this matrix by

```
sub3 <- subset(data.df, V1 == "General0" && V2 == "0")
```

this command doesn't work correctly and just select all the frame. remember that my file has different values in the first and second columns.

can you help me how can i select a subset of matrix.

```
         V1 V2           V3
1  General0  0 1.2946021618
2  General0  0 1.0946334452
3  General0  0 0.8449582803
4  General0  0 0.5990934855
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [deviding a storing a file as different vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695027/deviding-a-storing-a-file-as-different-vectors)

Comment: i deleted that one. sorry

Comment: I want to know how can i subset a matrix

Comment: Ok, but the other question was better than this one, as it was less trivially answered by the documentation.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to learn how to post good questions (and therefore get faster and better answers)

Comment: I think this is clear. I don't know what is your problem?

Comment: I need to check first and second columns for each row and select the third column if the row match the conditions.

Comment: i changed the question.

Comment: Your way of reading your textfile seems a bit strange. What is wrong with `data <- read.table("sample1.txt", header=T)`? Afterwards, pleas show us `data[1:10,]`, or even better `dput(data[1:10,])`. What does `str(data)` look like?

Comment: > dput(data[1:10,])
structure(c("General0", "General0", "General0", "General0", "General0", 
"General0", "General0", "General0", "General0", "General0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1.2946021618", 
"1.0946334452", "0.8449582803", "0.5990934855", "0.3628845848", 
"0.1328743394", "0.0068609134", "0.0107383326", "0.0001648070", 
"0.0001641485"), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", 
"V2", "V3")))

Comment: when I just tried to choose one column, it works fine like: > sub3 <- subset(data.df, V2 == "0")
but when I try it with two arguments, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: What did you find strange in my importing command, I have taken it from R manual.

Comment: You probably misinterpreted the point of the example in the manual. In your case, you end up converting all your numeric data to characters (or factors, depending on your default settings), which (unless you're doing something very strange) surely isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `&&`. `&&` is a logical operation that only works on scalar booleans (with shortcut ability, thus if the first expression is `FALSE`, the other expressions never are evaluated.). When doing logical expressions with vectors, just use a plain `&`:

```
sub3 <- subset(data.df, V1 == "General0" & V2 == "0")
```

Your import is a bit complicated. `read.table` returns you a perfect `data.frame` of your dataset. Thus, converting the output of `read.table` to a matrix and then reconverting it to a `data.frame` has only one effect. You convert all values to characters (as you have one character column) and then create a data.frame with those character values, with the result that the columns `V2` and `V3` are converted as factors.

If there is a valid reason to have all columns as factors, this is a valid (yet uncommon) approach. However, I can hardly imagine a use case for that. I would like

```
data <- read.table("sample1.txt", header = F)
sub <- subset(data, V1 == 'General0' & V2 == 0)
```

much better.

---

### Edit

If you just need one column, you have at least three options (that are all well documented, by the way):

```
col3 <- sub3$V3
```

or

```
col3 <- with(data.df, V3[V1=='General0' & V2 == '0')
```

or

```
col3 <- data.df$V3[data.df$V1 == 'General0' & data.df&V2 == '0'])
```

Comment: how can I select just the third column in sub3?

Comment: ...or the `select` argument in `subset`, also well documented. But based on the now deleted original version of @user2312186's question, none of this is really going to be a good solution to their actual problem, IMHO.

Comment: Still, all those are techniques that are good to know. Without the original question, we will not be able to help with the actual problem. Anyway: @user2312186 if this solved your question, you can mark it as solved by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. This way nobody else has to open the question and look at your problem.

Comment: when I try to import the file like you i got this                    Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'V1' not found

Comment: also, when I wanted to use col3 <- sub3$V3 I got  Error in sub3$V3 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors do you know what is thsi exactly?

Comment: Honestly, all your problems probably become clear just by *looking* at the objects you have. Did you ever enter just `sub3` and check if it is of the form you expected it to be? What might have happened? We are glad to help you, but you also have to bring some minimal effort. Learn the basics of `R` (using one of the many tutorials out there) and you will understand what is going wrong there. Then you may be able to solve this kind of problems yourself.